# Load an image or display letter when image not available in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to test if image exists else display letter in place of image but couldn't get it to work.

```
app.controller('task1Controller',['$scope', 'taskFactory', '$state', 'imageTestService', function($scope, taskFactory, $state, imageTestService){

    $scope.taskData = {};
    $scope.current = 0;

    taskFactory.get().then(function(response){
        $scope.jsonData = response.data.resultCareGivers;
    });

    $scope.IsValidImageUrl = function(url){        
        imageTestService.IsValidImageUrl(url);
    };

    $scope.back = function(){
        $scope.current = ($scope.current !== 0 ? $scope.current - 1 : 0);
    };

    $scope.next = function(){
        $scope.current = ($scope.current !== $scope.jsonData.length-1 ? $scope.current + 1 : $scope.jsonData.length-1);
    };

}]);
```

Service to test image:

```
app.service('imageTestService', function(){

    this.IsValidImageUrl = function(url){
        var img = new Image();
        img.onerror = function() { return false; };
        img.onload =  function() { return true; };
        img.src = url;
    };

});
```

Html:

```
<div ng-if=IsValidImageUrl(jsonData[current].profilepic)>
    <img ng-model="jsonData[current].profilepic"/>
</div>
<div ng-if=!IsValidImageUrl(jsonData[current].profilepic)>
    <div>{{jsonData[current].firstName.charAt(1)+jsonData[current].lastName.charAt(1)}}</div>
</div>
```

But the problem is `jsonData[current].profilepic` inside html `ng-if` condition is not available on load of the page which shows incorrect result even though image is present inside json.

json:

```
{
    "resultCareGivers": 
    [
        {
            "firstName":"aaa",
            "lastName":"bbb",
            "email":"bbb@mail.com",
            "profilepic":"http://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
        },
        {
            "firstName":"xxx",
            "lastName":"yyy",
            "email":"xxx@mail.com",
            "profilepic":"",
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the value

```
  $scope.IsValidImageUrl = function(url){        
       return  imageTestService.IsValidImageUrl(url);
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in your code

First you are not returning anything back to the view and also check if anything is returning from the service

```
  $scope.IsValidImageUrl = function(url){        
       return  imageTestService.IsValidImageUrl(url);
  };
```

Second you are using `ng-model` to bind an image. Instead you have to use `ng-src`

```
<div ng-if=IsValidImageUrl(jsonData[current].profilepic)>
    <img ng-src="{{jsonData[current].profilepic}}"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Updated the code, I still get `failed to load resource error` for image. The json contains `http://via.placeholder.com/350x150` which is valid image url

Comment: jsonData[current].profilepic contains http://via.placeholder.com/350x150? Or is it some other property?

Comment: Its a image url

Comment: Try printing {{ jsonData[current].profilepic}} on view and check if the value is coming properly or not?

Comment: Yeah its coming properly when I print. It prints `http://via.placeholder.com/350x150` but the image doesn't load into ng-src

Comment: Idk then there will be some other problem. I suspect the problem is arising from IsValidImageUrl function. Maybe try removing img.src from there and put a debugger and debug

Comment: Why are u creating a new image in IsValidImageUrl  function . Just check if the url is a valid image and return true , otherwise return false.